# SQLite GROUP BY slower with index

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, indexing, group-by

I have a very simple table in SQLite with 500,000 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE db (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, firstname TEXT)
```

I run this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM db 
ORDER BY name
```

It takes about 3 seconds without any index.
But with the following index it takes about 9 seconds to show the results:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON db(name)
```

Why is this query 3 times slower with an index as without one? In my understanding it should be a lot faster with an index.

EDIT:
These are the query plans:
[image]

Comment: Please post [query plan](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for both queries.

Comment: Also a good rule of thumb is to run [ANALYZE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) on a populated table after adding a new index and execute `PRAGMA optimize` just before closing a database. This lets the query planner make informed decisions about which indexes to use and the latter updates the statistics if needed.

Comment: I'm using the sqlite3 node module and the query plan didn't work. So i used that db-file in sqlite directly. I attached the query plans to my original post. So if there is no index for name it is created temporary, if there is an index for name it uses a covering index. This should be fine? I looked up the sys time for the queries and the one with covering index is faster. Could the sqlite3 node module cause this behaviour?

Comment: Based on that the version with the index should be faster as it never touches the actual table (it just has name and rowid columns?), and just iterates over the already sorted index. And sounds like it is indeed faster in the shell? I don't know why it wouldn't in node too then.